# Parameter is not valid datagridview default error dialog

Tags: c#, winforms

```
BindingList<Item> itemList = new BindingList<Item>();
        foreach (Item item in po.Items)
        {
            itemList.Add(item);
        }
        ==> dgvItems.DataSource = itemList;
        dgvItems.Columns["ItemId"].Visible = false;
```

When I run my program it throws the error at the line I marked with "==>" I don't know where the error is coming from because when I debug the list contains valid data. It was working before so I think the error appears since I did some changes to the timestamp repository code.

This is my Item object definition:

```
public class Item
{
    public byte[] TimeStamp { get; set; }

    public int ItemId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Item Name is required")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Description is required")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Price is required")]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Location is required")]
    public string Location { get; set; }

    //public byte[] TimeStamp { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Justification is required")]
    public string Justification { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Quantity is required")]
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    public int PurchaseOrderId { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public ItemStatus Status { get; set; }

    public Item()
    {

    }

    public Item(int itemId, string name, string description, decimal price, string location, string justification, int quantity, int purchaseOrderId, DateTime date, ItemStatus status)
    {
        ItemId = itemId;
        Name = name;
        Description = description;
        Price = price;
        Location = location;
        Justification = justification;
        Quantity = quantity;
        PurchaseOrderId = purchaseOrderId;
        Date = date;
        Status = status;
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the `Item` object definition. Btw, you can fill a BindingList with `var itemList = new BindingList<Item>(po.Items);`

Comment: I think the timestamp is conflicting with the datagridview it probably can't display it, is there a way around? and thanks for the suggestion

Comment: When you provide a byte array to the DGV without using any type converter, the DGV tries to generate a Bitmap from it. Of course it fails, hence the error. The Item's constructor doesn't even include the TimeStamp property. How would you like to see this property represented in the grid? Do you actually need to *see* this value or not? In case it should be visible, should it also be editable? Did you create a corresponding Column in the DGV designer or the Columns are auto-generated?

Comment: I don't need to see the value and the columns are auto-generated

Answer (score 1):

Here a couple of option, see what better fits.

**Option 1**:

Add a [`[Browsable(false)]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.browsableattribute) attribute to the Item class object:
The DataGridView won't generate a Column for TimeStamp property.

To note that:

> *Members marked with the BrowsableAttribute constructor's browsable
>   parameter set to false are not appropriate for design-time editing and
>   therefore are not displayed in a visual designer.*

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class Item
{
    [Browsable(false)]
    public byte[] TimeStamp { get; set; }
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Item Name is required")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //[...]
}
```

**Option 2**:

Remove the Column right after the `DataGridView.DataSource` has been set:

To note that you won't be able to modify the TimeStamp value through the DataGridView. But, as mentioned in comments, this property doesn't need to be modified.

```
var itemList = new BindingList<Item>(po.Items);
dataGridView1.DataSource = itemList;
dataGridView1.Columns.Remove("TimeStamp");
```